# Python extracts web links from the Current Estimates of the U.S. Census Bureau and outputs links in a CSV in an absolute and non-duplicated format

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Using Jupyter notebook I started pulling all of the HTML links from the Current Estimates webpage from the US Census Bureau. Everything seems to be parsing out fine until I get down to Input 13 which is supposed to retrieve elements by class equal to uscb using the attributes argument. The uscb seemed to be similar in all links but when I run the code the output is empty.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all({'class':'uscb-'})` will look for exact matches, which it won't find any. It also won't find anything because you haven't a specified tag. What you need to do is search for classes that contain that substring, which you can use regex. And include the tag:

```
import re

soup.find_all('a',{'class':re.compile(r'uscb')})
```

If you want to find that class, regardless of the tag, then you can also use regex for that:

```
import re

soup.find_all(re.compile(r'(\w+)'),{'class':re.compile(r'uscb')})
```